# Excel Lookup against another Workbook?

Tags: excel

I have two Excel workbooks with 1 sheet in each.
Workbook1 Addresses contains:
A – Full Name
B – Address
C - Zipcode
D – Employee ID

Workbook2
A – First Name
B – Last Name
C – Zipcode

How can I run a lookup from Workbook2 that will return the Employee ID when Zipcode in both sheets match and [First Name] in contained in [Full Name] And [Last Name] is contained in [Full Name}?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.

Define the table array to reference the data in the other workbook, or even define it with a name, see Insert: Names: Define.

You can also consider putting both sheets in the same workbook. This can avoid issues of moving one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Formula to get the ID

```
=INDEX([WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$D$20;MATCH(1;([WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$2:$C$21=C2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(A2);[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$20)))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(B2);[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$20)));0);4)
```

Example Workbooks:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkguUf50ts_Fn128VILg?e=fvQ2BT

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkguUhKts9cShLgGw_xg?e=IJitts

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't get it fully working yet. I think it would help if I understood what is the first parameter (the 1) in the MATCH, and second parameter in the INDEX (the 4)?

Comment: @Shirolee The 4 in the Index is the 3rd parameter (1st Array, 2nd Row, 3rd Column) - It is the 4th column in the Array. So in this Array [WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$D$20 it means column D, because in this case column D is the 4th column. If we had an array B2:E20 then the 4 would be column E.
Don't change the 1 in the Match. If you evaluate the Lookup-Array in the Match function you get: MATCH(1;{0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;#N/A};0). Only 1, 0 or Error. Match is searching for the first 1 in this array. In this example in *row 5 of the array*. Which is *sheet row 6* in WB1.