# How to search on multiple columns in ecxel "vlookup" and return value from another column in the same row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I have an excel file.
Its purpose is to have a list of rooms (working rooms), and people names, so I can know TWO things:

1. Who is embedded in each room.
2. What is the room of a specific person.

The file has 2 spreadsheets in it.

The first one (called “people”) is a list of names, with another column which says what is the room of each person. Note: There are NOT two identical names. Every name is different.
[image]

The second one (called “rooms”) is a list of 5 columns:

- the first column is the room number
- the other 4, are 4 names of people (because each room has 4 people in it). Note: the order of the people in the room (in the 4 columns) is not important.
  [image]

The problem starts when I want to swap 2 people from different rooms. Then, I have to change it in both spreadsheets.
I want to find a formula that finds a name in “rooms” spreadsheet, and writes the room number (column A) in the correct row in “people” spreadsheet in column B.

I have tried to use one of the `lookup` formulas (and especially `vlookup`) but the problem is the fact that those functions search only in the first column and return value from the other columns, whereas I need exactly the opposite: I want to find value (specific name) from one of the 4 columns, and return the value of the first column (the room number - column A). That way I can go to B column in “people” spreadsheet, and insert a formula for each name in it, so it can find the correct room number.

Another problem is the fact that the room numbers in “rooms” spreadsheet are not necessarily sorted. Sometimes I want to take a group and move it to a different room. In this case, all I do is changing the room number in column A, thing that makes the list to be not-sorted.

How can I do this with a formula, in a way that I will need to change only the people in "rooms" spreadsheet, and not to change room number in "people" spreadsheet? Is there a formula that does what I need, or should I use more than one formula to achieve my goal?

Comment: Use index() with match() so columns can be in any order unlike vlookup.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: If you have used vlookup then index with match is only separating out the looking up parts of the indexing value and the resulting value. There are so many examples on here of their use.

Comment: Just one of many examples, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71194313/4961700

Comment: OK, I will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **[INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)** & **[AGGREGATE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)** Function

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=INDEX(rooms!$A$4:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(rooms!$B$4:$E$8)-ROW(rooms!$B$4)+1)/(people!$A4=rooms!$B$4:$E$8),1))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

So let me explain how `AGGREGATE()` Function returns the position of each emp, actually it returns the row number in which emp falls in

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(rooms!$B$4:$E$8)-ROW(rooms!$B$4)+1)/(people!$A4=rooms!$B$4:$E$8),1)
```

[image: RETURNS_ROW_NUMBER]

Next when wrapped within an `INDEX()` Function it outputs the Room Numbers as desired.

Refer the image below, when altered !

[image: ALTERATION]

Comment: It did worked, but I want to understand the things I write. I didn't understand the use of `AGGREGATE` function. I have tried to learn about this function, and also about `ROW` function, but I don't understand the connection between them. Furthermore, when I took parts of the formula and put them in other cells (and then in the original formula put a reference to the correct cell) it didn't do the same thing!! I didn't understand why.

Comment: @php123 the `AGGREGATE()` Function is used to generate a list of rows (i.e. positions) where the selected `Emp` is discovered.  The advantage of using the `AGGREGATE()` function is that it can accept multiple answers without the use of `CTRL` + `Shift` + `Enter`. The `ROW()` function calculates the row number of a cell reference. It can also return an array of row numbers if the reference is a cell range.
`ROW(reference)` - so in the example --> `ROW(rooms!$B$4:$E$8)` this becomes `{4;5;6;7;8}` and the whole part `ROW(rooms!$B$4:$E$8)-ROW(rooms!$B$4)+1` when equated returns `{1;2;3;4;5}` .

Comment: Therefore when we divide the above whole array with `(people!$A4=rooms!$B$4:$E$8)` which is nothing but `{FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}` shall return `{#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;2,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!}` giving us the actual position of the `Emp`

Comment: @php123 to avoid the `#DIV/0!` error we `6` in `AGGREGATE()` function, the `1` in the last gives the kth position. So when you evaluate the whole formula of `AGGREGATE()` it shall give you the exact row number of the specified `Emp` i.e. 2 for the first cell and so on so forth.

Comment: @php123 if you are still facing issue could you share a `One-Drive` link so that I shall go through where is the error I can check because this formula is `ROBUST` and works !

Comment: Now I understand it. Thanks

Comment: @php123 here is a workbook link --> https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cg2nE2HbbxYf9MJuf?e=nzwW5b

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Formula in column B is:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$7;SUMPRODUCT(--($C$3:$F$7=A12)*ROW($B$3:$B$7))-2)
```

Notice the `-2` at the end. This is because data starts at row 3 so we need to adjust.

IF we swap 2 names (name 7 and 8) or 2 complete rooms (rooms 1 and 5) the results will autoupdate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Excel365; using LET for readability and alterability you can use:

```
=LET(data, rooms!B4:E8, index, MIN(IF(data=A4, ROW(data)+1))-ROW(INDEX(data,1,1)), INDEX(rooms!A4:A8, index))
```

Otherwise:

```
=INDEX(rooms!A4:A8,MIN(IF(rooms!B4:E8=A4,ROW(rooms!B4:E8)-3)))
```